# Good, free dataset to practice cross validation?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I've been searching online for free data sets with which I would be able to apply cross validation techniques. Preferably, I'd like to find data with ≈30 (or more) observations that has significant curvature so that I can demonstrate how one can use cross-validation to perform model selection.

I'd also like to demonstrate the use of a gradient estimation algorithm to estimate the polynomial parameters.

I would use the dataset to perform my final course project. I'd like to demonstrate that I have a good handle on the topics I mentioned above- so I am working backwards and trying to fit the data to the technique. I haven't had much luck searching online- most of the data sets I've found are either practice applications for linear regression or include many variables- which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'd greatly appreciate it!